# azure sql database intelligent search algorithm suggestions needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a sql database in Azure. The search algorithm would proceed more or less as follows:

It would consider a text field in Table_A, Field_A1, which contains a varying amount of text (nvarchar(max)). The algorithm would store a tunable number of words from Field_A1 (removing "this", "and", "CompanyName", etc.) and then return record results from another table, Table_B, by searching a field in Table_B, Field_B2 (also nvarchar(max)), which contain the tuned, stored words from Field_A1.

If it were a really smart algorithm, it would also recognize the patterns in which those words were used in Field_A1, and then only return records from Table_B, which corresponded to the same patterns found Field_B2.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider if a fulltext index work for this problem.

SQL Server/Azure works using a cost-based query processor.  We extended it with a mechanism to separate out words from textual data, find the common word stems, and allow query processing over this in a manner that is integrated with the cost-based query processor's plan selection process.

Ultimately this system allows you to mostly declare what is the shape of the output data you want to see and let SQL handle finding a decent algorithm to get this result to you as quickly as possible.